# ng-animate 1.5 - ng-animate-ref - not working on ios

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-transitions

I have set up a very basic plunkr to animate list element between two views with ng-animate 1.5 - ng-animate-ref.

It works for Firefox and Chrome but unfortunately it doesn't for iOS.

http://plnkr.co/edit/UDX9XlIi3hpYcmJZQ5WD

CSS

```
.row.ng-leave {
    transition: 0.2s linear all;
}

.row.ng-anchor-in-add {
    transition: 0.5s linear all;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="animated row" ng-repeat="i in a track by i" ng-animate-ref="item-{{i}}">{{i}}</div>

<br>

<div class="animated row" ng-repeat="i in b track by i" ng-animate-ref="item-{{i}}">{{i}}</div>

<a href="javascript:;" ng-click="start()">Start</a>
```

RESULT

[image: Animation of the effect]

Comment: My answer only worked in desktop Safari. Will look into it a bit more.

Comment: Well the bug seems to be the same for desktop and ios